# Is there a barcode scanner built in windows 10 or windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, barcode-scanner, barcode

I am looking for a barcode scanner on windows. Is there a barcode scanner built in windows 10 or windows 7?

Comment: There is no built in barcode scanner.  You will have to get 3rd party software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the camera to scan barcodes. There are a number of free applications to do so, e.g. [bcWebCam](http://www.bcwebcam.de/en/index.html).